# How can I know the docs changed,updated and indexed in solr index?

Tags: search, solr, indexing

While posting xml docs for indexing to solr, some docs are getting added and duplicate records are discarded. Some records are getting updated with new values as well. How Can I know these changes made to index. I mean how will I get to know the number of records added, no. of records updated, number of docs posted to solr core?

Answer (score 0):

In Solr 4, under the collection's section, there is a sub-section called *Plugins/Stats*. In it, there is category for UpdateHandler with the stats similar to what you are asking.

Also, it is possible to Watch for changes. Combined, this might give you a way to see if these are what you want. If they are, then you should be access the same values via JMX for more flexible/long-term tracking.

Comment: http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/admin/mbeans?stats=true
This url only tells the number of docs indexed,posted and discarded. But I wants to know the id of docs indexed(added), deleted while posting docs for indexing.I am implementing document duplication detection. So I wants to know the duplicate docs discarded by solr.

Comment: Or is there any way to know if the docs already exists in the solr-index before posting new xml file to the solr ??

Comment: These seem to be quite different questions from the one you started from. I suggesting closing this one and starting again. But quickly, have a look at UpdateRequestProcessors and perhaps the source for existing Solr Dedupe components.